# How do I change the line spacing in WinEdts editor (options interface...)?

Tags: winedt

I managed to change the font size in Options Interface. Now, a want to enlarge the line spacing. How I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options menu > Preferences > Font tab, change the value for `Extra Line Spacing` (0 by default):

[image]